# Flutter ListView not updating on data change

Tags: flutter, listview, flutter-layout, flutter-listview

I am new in Flutter. Currently learning and developing a flutter project. Here is my code. But my list view is not updating. Advance thanks for pointing out any mistake

```
    import 'package:cached_network_image/cached_network_image.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:get_it/get_it.dart';
import 'package:stacked/stacked.dart';
import 'package:sx_tvapp_app/data/network/models/favourite_item.dart';
import 'package:sx_tvapp_app/ui/views/favourite_items/favourite_items_viewmodel.dart';

class FavouriteItemsView extends StatefulWidget {
  final FavouriteItemsViewType type = FavouriteItemsViewType.one;
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    // TODO: implement createState
    return _FavouriteItemsViewState();
  }
}

class _FavouriteItemsViewState extends State<FavouriteItemsView> {
  final String title = 'お気に入り';

  List<String> items = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'];

  FavouriteItemPage page;
  List<FavouriteItemContent> contents = List();
  bool isLoading = false;

  FavouriteItemsViewModel viewModel;

  void showLoading() {
    setState(() {
      isLoading = true;
    });
  }

  Future loadData() async {
    print('loadData');
    print(contents.length.toString());
    if (page == null) {
      this.viewModel.getFavouriteItemForLoggedOutUser();
      showLoading();
    } else {
      if (page.totalPages > page.number) {
        this.viewModel.getFavouriteItemForLoggedOutUser(page: page.number + 1);
        showLoading();
      }
    }
  }

  void bindModel(FavouriteItemsViewModel viewModel) {
    viewModel.pageSubject.listen((value) {
      print(value);
      page = value;
    });

    viewModel.favouriteItemSubject.listen((value) {
      print(' content is going to be added');
      print(value.contents.length);
      setState(() {
//        contents.addAll(value.contents);
        for (int i = 0; i < value.contents.length; i++) {
          var commonItem = contents.where((element) {
            return element.id == value.contents[i].id;
          }).toList();
          if (commonItem.length == 0) {
            print('item is being addedf');
            contents.add(value.contents[i]);
          }
        }

//        contents = contents.toSet().toList();
        isLoading = false;
      });
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // TODO: implement build
    return ViewModelBuilder<FavouriteItemsViewModel>.reactive(
      viewModelBuilder: () => GetIt.instance.get<FavouriteItemsViewModel>(),
      onModelReady: (model) {
        this.viewModel = model;
        this.bindModel(model);
//        this.loadData();
        model.getFavouriteItemForLoggedOutUser();
      },
      builder: (context, viewModel, child) {
        return Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text(title),
          ),
          body: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Expanded(
                child: NotificationListener<ScrollNotification>(
                  onNotification: (ScrollNotification scrollInfo) {
                    if (!isLoading &&
                        scrollInfo.metrics.pixels ==
                            scrollInfo.metrics.maxScrollExtent) {
                      loadData();
                    }
                  },
                  child: buildListView(),
                ),
              ),
              Container(
                height: isLoading ? 50.0 : 0,
                color: Colors.transparent,
                child: Center(
                  child: new CircularProgressIndicator(),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }

  Widget buildListView() {
    return ListView.builder(
        itemCount: contents.length,
        padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 9, 0, 9),
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return buildRow(contents[index]);
        });
  }

  Widget buildRow(FavouriteItemContent content) {
    return Column(
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
      children: <Widget>[
        Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              width: 15,
              height: 0,
            ),
//TODO: Handle this after null image url issue is fixed
//            CachedNetworkImage(
//              fit: BoxFit.fill,
//              height: 25,
//              width: 25,
//              imageUrl: content.channelIconUrl,
//              placeholder: (context, url) => CircularProgressIndicator(),
//              errorWidget: (context, url, error) => new Icon(Icons.error),
//            ),
            getImage(content.channelIconUrl, 25, 25),
            Container(
              width: 9,
              height: 0,
            ),
            Container(
              child: Text(
                content.name,
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 12,
                  letterSpacing: -0.25,
                  color: Color.fromRGBO(96, 96, 96, 1.0),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
        Container(
          width: 0,
          height: 30,
        ),
//TODO: Handle this after null image url issue is fixed
//        CachedNetworkImage(
//          fit: BoxFit.fill,
//          height: 211,
//          width: double.infinity,
//          imageUrl: content.imageUrl,
//          placeholder: (context, url) => CircularProgressIndicator(),
//          errorWidget: (context, url, error) => new Icon(Icons.error),
//        ),
        getImage(content.imageUrl, double.infinity, 211),
        Container(
          width: 0,
          height: 13,
        ),
        Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(15, 12.5, 15, 9),
          child: Text(content.details),
        )
      ],
    );
  }

  Widget getImage(String url, double width, double height) {
    if (url != null) {
      return CachedNetworkImage(
        imageUrl: url,
        placeholder: (context, url) => CircularProgressIndicator(),
        errorWidget: (context, url, error) => Image(
          image: AssetImage(
              'assets/images/product_detail/product_detail_placeholder.png'),
        ),
      );
    } else {
      return Image(
        width: width,
        height: height,
        image: AssetImage(
            'assets/images/product_detail/product_detail_placeholder.png'),
      );
    }
  }
}

enum FavouriteItemsViewType { one, two, three, four }
```

The thing I do here is, I request for a get API at the beginning which gives me data for the first page. Then I request again after scrolling down to the bottom. This is a ListView with pagination.

Comment: This question would better fit in Discord channel or similar. The answer of the question needs to be helpful to other people who views this page the future, not just for you.

Comment: @easeccy I don't have any idea about Discord. Can you elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

What you would likely want to use is a StreamBuilder which will rebuild whatever it contains when new data arrives from the stream. Streambuilder will become your go to for most data in flutter.

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/StreamBuilder-class.html

Comment: I am going to try StreamBuilder and check